# What is the minimum amount of HTML an UpdatePanel requires before it falls over?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, response.write

If for instance, I was to give a response back to an ASP.Net Update Panel page, but use Response.Write and then end it before anything was rendered, what is the minimum I would need to write in the Response.Write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the following UpdatePanel ...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updatePanel" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID ="textbox1"/>
        <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="go" OnClick="OnGo" text="Go"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

... then click the button and view the response in Firebug, you'll get something like this (I've truncated the viewstate and event validation to make it a bit more readable):

```
265|updatePanel|updatePanel|
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="content" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" id="go" />|
52|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|/wXPZwUK...|
64|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|/wEWB...|
0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||0|postBackControlIDs|||
12|updatePanelIDs||tupdatePanel|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||
11|panelsToRefreshIDs||updatePanel|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|20|
formAction||Upagename.aspx|13|pageTitle||Untitled Page|
```

All that extra data is stuff that the `ScriptManager` needs to rebuild the contents of the UpdatePanel: control ids, the page name, viewstate, etc.. This is what you'd have to `Response.Write` manually for the `ScriptManager` to be able to do its job.

For details, see "[ScriptManager Enables AJAX In Your Web Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx#S7)". At the end of the section titled "Putting the AJAX in ASP.NET AJAX", the author explains what's going on:

> Finally, the client framework gets the
>   asynchronous response from the server
>   and parses out data. The ScriptManager
>   control has packed into the response
>   all the control IDs and new markup so
>   the client framework can simply
>   perform scripting operations on the
>   browser's document object model to
>   update the page content.